# Kafka Streams Processor API: Write directly to kafka statestore and then to topic to avoid latency

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application which produces to a topic. In the same application, I query its materialized state store for getting the latest value for a particular key.

I have to immediately query the state store as soon as the data is produced to the topic. Most of the time, the interactive query returns old value as it would take some time for updating the value in state store.

I am thinking of changing the architecture and I would like to know if it possible to write directly to state store first and then to final topic so that I can get the updated value as soon as it is available. If this is possible and say I have multiple instances of the same application, how can I query the local state store of other instances as I might not have a source stream?

I know interactive queries work on top of a Kafka stream with source topic. But in my case, if I directly write to a statestore, will rpc work?How can I achieve it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Writing to the topic needs to happen first. Otherwise, the data would be out of sync. Why do you need to query the store rather than consume from the topic?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I need to query the value only when an invocation happens (in my case, it is the rest endpoint of the application). This call can happen either within a second or after some time from which the previous value of key is set.

Comment: But if you produce a message "when invocation happens", then a consumer will then see that, right? I assume that's what you mean by "immediately". StateStores don't have notification channels unless you build them (by using their underlying topics)

Comment: Just to be sure is this what your application does ? reads messages from a topic, updates a local store, and queries the store using REST API. Also, I understand you will be using a Global KTable which is replicated on each instance. So even if you write the update to the local state store first and then to the topic, the update will not be seen on a different instance until the state store on that instance loads the changes from the topic.